# i am always getting an Error in MySql Query: Error 1054: Unknown column 'column name' in field list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is my MySQL Query that im trying to execute. it keeps failing with the error: 
Unknown column 'staff_tbl.mainrank' in field list. how is this possible?

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `staff_tbl`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE staff_tbl(childrank TEXT, mainrank TEXT);

INSERT INTO staff_tbl
SELECT permissions_inheritance.child, permissions_inheritance.parent 
FROM permissions_inheritance;

SELECT      authme.username, permissions_inheritance.child,     
permissions_inheritance.parent, staff_tbl.mainrank
FROM        authme 
INNER JOIN  permissions_inheritance ON authme.username = permissions_inheritance.child
INNER JOIN  staff_tbl alies2 ON staff_tbl.mainrank = permissions_inheritance.parent;


DROP TABLE `staff_tbl`;
```

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me. i have pulled every bit of my hair out. so you guys are my last hope. Im still a novice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last `SELECT` you have the last join wrong. You make a join with `staff_tbl` and give it an alias (`alies2`). You must use that alias in the statement that follows (`alies2.mainrank = permissions_inheritance.parent` instead of `staff_tbl.mainrank = permissions_inheritance.parent`), you didn't.

Try writing your last `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT      a.username, p.child, p.parent, s.mainrank
FROM        authme a
INNER JOIN  permissions_inheritance p ON a.username = p.child
INNER JOIN  staff_tbl s ON s.mainrank = p.parent;
```

I fixed this above. I also set an alias for each table to make the query shorter and therefore more readable.

Comment: Thanks Very Much, It worked! if u dont mind, could you please explain why this worked?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows to create two tables with the same name if one of them is **temporary**.

In the query you trying to join temporary table, but MySQL joins another non-temporary `staff_tbl` table which does not contain `mainrank` field.

So, drop this non-temporary table firstly.